# Vue js vuelidate custom validation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model, vuelidate

I'm creating  basic stock management system. In there, the invoicing I want to validate,
the price user enter must be greater than or equal to the minimum selling price.
I use [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) package for the validations.

Any clue how to achieve this using vuelidate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a `custom validator` called `price_greater` as follow :

```
   const price_greater = (value, vm) => (value >= vm.min_price);
```

and add it to `validations` property :

```
validations: {
    user_price: {
         required,
         price_greater
       }
}
```

check the following example:

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const {
  required
} = window.validators;
const price_greater =
  (value, vm) => (value >= vm.min_price);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      min_price: 455,
      user_price: 0,
      respectMinPrice: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    status(validation) {
      return {
        error: validation.$error,
        dirty: validation.$dirty
      }
    }
  },

  validations: {

    user_price: {
      required,
      price_greater
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/validators.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <input v-model="$v.user_price.$model" placeholder="user_price" type="number" :class="status($v.user_price)">

  <p class="error" v-show="respectMinPrice">user price must be greater or equal to min selling price</p>
</div>
```

if you're working with single file component check [this solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2n99onq78)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I looked for. First I go thorough the docs and confused with the term vm. So the vm means data object of the component. User has a drop down to select the items which means the min_price also change according to the item. So for that is it okay to change the min_price by a computed property or is there more elegant solution for that? anyways thanks a lot. =)